# How to disable graphics.redraw when map pans

Tags: arcgis-js-api

I have a map when you pan or zoom in and out any graphics drawn on the map will all default to the last color used and I found that there is a method that is called when the map pans or extent changes which is graphics.redraw(). MY question is how to disable this or prevent it from happening so that my polygons dont  fill with the last colour used.

I have tried suspending and resuming the graphics layer that did not work
I have tried to add a new graphics layer and that still has not worked 
I have tried to clear the color picker I use (spectrum) after drawing the graphic to the map and that still has not worked.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: How are you adding the different colors to the graphics? I had a somewhat similar problem with marker symbols added as graphics being redrawn incorrectly after a map zoom.  My problem was that I was adding the angle to the marker variable itself, rather than to each individual instance of the marker.  You may need to add your colors to each element in the graphics array individually.